# How to disable animation while opening dialog in angular material 2 with angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create the dialog but problem is I want to disable the animation in  the dialog so how to disable it.

Comment: `import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';` instead of `import { BrowserAnimationsModule } '@angular/platform-browser/animations';` in your main `AppModule` and place in the `imports` array. This turns off animations altogether. Outside of that it's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to keep your animations on your app but being able to disable the one attached to a dialog you can override the dialog container by one you can control and disable all the animations inside that container.

**Override OverlayContainer component**

- Create a custom OverlayContainer which extends the one from the cdk

  ```
  import { OverlayContainer } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

  export class CustomOverlayContainer extends OverlayContainer {
      _defaultContainerElement: HTMLElement;

      constructor() {
          super();
      }

      public setContainer( container: HTMLElement ) {
          this._defaultContainerElement = this._containerElement;
          this._containerElement = container;
      }

      public restoreContainer() {
          this._containerElement = this._defaultContainerElement;
      }
  }
  ```
- Override the cdk OverlayContainer by the custom one on the app module providers

  ```
  export function initOverlay() {
      return new CustomOverlayContainer();
  }
  @NgModule( {
       ...
       providers: [
           ...
           {
               provide: OverlayContainer,
               useFactory: initOverlay
           }
           ...
       ]
       ...
  })
  ```

**Replace the dialog wrapper**

Get access to the new dialog container and replace the default one

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild( 'dialogContainer' ) dialogContainer: ElementRef;

    constructor( private dialog: MatDialog, private overlayContainer: OverlayContainer ) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        (this.overlayContainer as CustomOverlayContainer).setContainer( this.dialogContainer.nativeElement );

        this.dialog.open( ... );
    }
}
```

**Disable animations**

Add the `[@.disabled]` binding to your container in order to disable all the animations happening inside it. https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger#disable-animations

```
<div #dialogContainer [@.disabled]="true"></div>
```

Comment: Any idea how to modify the animation to animate down instead of up?

Comment: I tried using this technique to substitute my own animation trigger, instead of `[@.disabled]` and my trigger was ignored.  @Yuri any way to use my own animation trigger (for sliding in from the right side) instead of disabling the built in one?

Comment: @yuri, it works **BUT** it disable all other components that uses the `defaultContainerElement`, for example `matMenu` (vertical three dots), I can see the `restore` function but how can I use it in such a way that when the app initializes all other component that use the `defaultContainerElement` will act as normal?

Answer (score 11):

you can disable by importing

> NoopAnimationsModule

```
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [NoopAnimationsModule],
  ...
})
```

more info 
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: If I want to disable the animation in specific condition then what should I do.

Comment: try add  transition in your component  field example  .mat-dialog-container{
transition: none;
}

Comment: happy to help!!

Comment: This doesn't work to me, I think it's not a transition anymore.

Comment: This is like turning off your TV by going to the switch breaker :-/

Answer (score 2):

#### Angular Material 7 has a **much** nicer animation.

It should alleviate the problem for most developers wanting to disable it.

It opens from the center, zooming in slightly and without sliding up or down. On close it disappears instantly. It also behaves nicely on phones where the bottom toolbar is initially hidden.

It should perform much better on less capable graphics cards, older phones or dialogs with complex content.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the same problem. Angular material lib still doesn't have a clean way to disable/configure animations for specific overlay component. However, there's one hack I found that works well enough for my use-case.

So, idea is to overwrite the animations that are attached to a certain Angular Material Component (e.g. `mat-select`, `mat-menu`, etc.). In Angular Material git you can find `<component>-animations.ts` files next to components that have all default animations declared (e.g. https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/select/select-animations.ts - for `mat-select`).

Knowing those - we can overwrite decorator properties of each of material components we want to change animation for. Note that this would only do it per component type (i.e. not per instance).

**Here's how to disable animations for `mat-select` dropdown:**

```js
MatSelect['decorators'][0].args[0].animations[0] = trigger('transformPanelWrap', []);
MatSelect['decorators'][0].args[0].animations[1] = trigger('transformPanel', []);
```

The above snippet removes all the animations for `mat-select` dropdown. The trigger names are taken from the files described above (check material sources). You could also easily replace existing animations with custom ones the same way e.g.

```js
MatSelect['decorators'][0].args[0].animations[1] = trigger('transformPanel', [
    state('void', style({
       transform: 'scale(0.1)',
       opacity: 0
    })),
]);
```

*Indexes inside `animations` array correspond to the original animations declarations order. `['decorators'][0].args[0]` is always the same.*

Originally idea from: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8857#issuecomment-401793529