# Angular material dialog animation terribly slow on mobile

Tags: android, angular, google-chrome, animation, angular-material2

On my Xperia M5 running marshmallow, angular material's dialog's opening animation is terrible in chrome, even on [angular material's own website](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview). Is there a way I can disable animations only on mobile for the dialog?

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611446/how-to-disable-animation-while-opening-dialog-in-angular-material-2-with-angular), but it suggests disabling all animations, and the CSS solution doesn't work.

P.S. I'm running Angular 5 and everything is updated to stable.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @GustavoAriasMéndez, nope, nothing yet :/

Comment: Are you experiencing same issue with v9 ?

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did to disable dialog animations just on android devices.

I used Ng2DeviceService to determine whether it was an android device.  Could be easily modified to look for other conditions.

This works for angular 5.  Not sure about older versions.

I did this all in my app.module.ts

Add imports

```
import { AnimationDriver, ɵWebAnimationsDriver, ɵNoopAnimationDriver } from '@angular/animations/browser';
```

Create an animation factory.

```
 /**
 * Disable animations for dialogs on slow devices
 * @returns {WebAnimationsDriver}
 */
const animationFactory = () => {
  const deviceService = new Ng2DeviceService();
  const noop = AnimationDriver.NOOP;
  const driver = new ɵWebAnimationsDriver();
  const originalAnimate = driver.animate;

  const isAndroid = deviceService.os === 'android';

  let disableComplexAnimations = false;
  if (isAndroid) {
    disableComplexAnimations = true;
  }

  driver.animate = (element: any, keyframes: {
    [key: string]: string | number;
  }[], duration: number, delay: number, easing: string, previousPlayers?: any[]) => {
    if (disableComplexAnimations && element && element.nodeName === 'MAT-DIALOG-CONTAINER') {
      return noop.animate(element, keyframes, duration, delay, easing, previousPlayers);
    } else {
      return originalAnimate(element, keyframes, duration, delay, easing, previousPlayers);
    }
  };
  return driver;
};
```

Register is in your providers list:

```
  providers: [
    { provide: AnimationDriver, useFactory: animationFactory },
  ],
```

Comment: Any token prefixed by `ɵ` should not be used. They are considered private and could break at any time.