# Remove/override mat-dialog opening animation

Tags: angular

I want to remove the transition/animation on mat-dialog, so that it just shows without any animation.

Is it possible and how?

Need some help on this.

```
"@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
```

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611446/how-to-disable-animation-while-opening-dialog-in-angular-material-2-with-angular

Answer (score 0):

For just this component you can add the css

```
.mat-dialog { transition: none; }
```

If you want to disable the complete animation for a module then you have to import the [NoopAnimationsModule](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/NoopAnimationsModule) which is a dummy animation module that does simply nothing.

Comment: .mat-dialog { transition: none; }
 Not working for me!